# Primary Key Insert violation sometimes happening, but statement checks this

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Maybe someone has an idea what I can check:

```cs
      using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connection))
      {
        cnn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
          cmd.Connection = cnn;
          cmd.CommandText = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kruserprofile WHERE lactorid=@1 AND strname=@2) " +
                            "  UPDATE kruserprofile SET txtvalue=@3 WHERE lactorid=@1 AND strname=@2 " +
                            "ELSE " +
                            "  INSERT INTO kruserprofile (lactorid, strname, txtvalue) " +
                            "  VALUES (@1, @2, @3)";
          cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", actorId);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", ident);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", _mXml.ToString());
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        cnn.Close();
      }
```

As you can see in this piece of code I do check if records exists and update or insert.
This works pretty fine on SQL Server systems.
On Azure SQL I do sometimes but not reproduce able the error:
`Violation on PRIMARY KEY...` where the constraint is on `lactorid` and `strname`.

Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.kruserprofile (
    lactorid int NOT NULL,
    strname nvarchar(254) NOT NULL,
    txtvalue nvarchar(max) NULL
);
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.kruserprofile ADD CONSTRAINT PK__kruserpr__6E092EE804688C07 PRIMARY KEY (lactorid, strname);
GO
```

So I did not find any reason why, but sometimes it seems that the `EXISTS`returns false so it try to insert which fails then. Any idea what I can check?

Comment: It's called concurrency. There's a gap of time between the check and the insert. You may be able to use `MERGE`.

Comment: [Please stop using this UPSERT anti-pattern](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)

Comment: Found this https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern which gave me all I need...

Comment: See also [AddWithValue is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @Charlieface this was not my problem here, but good tip anyway! I will refactor on this, too, thanks!

Comment: Also I personally put the whole string as one verbatim block (no concatenation, just newlines) in a const string like so `const string query = @"UPDATE ...` then create the command `using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn))` Personal preference though, it looks neater to me

Comment: *"Found this"* That is the article I linked (about 40 minutes before your comment ;) ).

Comment: 3min not on this screen, apologize :)

Comment: I think you'd better consider about using [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I thinks Aarons post shows a pretty easy, fast and working solution. I checked those MERGE stuff and it looks much overhead on it or at least hard to memorize the usage.

Comment: Hi @YvesR. It seems that you've found the solution previously. So can you correct my answer and accept(mark) it as answer ? This can be beneficial to other community members. Very Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update:**

**Solution1:**

> We also have found the solution [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern).

---

**Solution2:**

> I've created a test about using [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in Azure SQL.

1. Create table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.kruserprofile (
    lactorid int NOT NULL,
    strname nvarchar(254) NOT NULL,
    txtvalue nvarchar(max) NULL
);
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.kruserprofile ADD CONSTRAINT PK__kruserpr__6E092EE804688C07 PRIMARY KEY (lactorid, strname);
GO
```

2. Create a Table-valued parameter named `dbo.kruserprofile_type`, it will be used in my stored procedure:

```sql
create TYPE dbo.kruserprofile_type AS TABLE(
    lactorid int NOT NULL,
    strname nvarchar(254) NOT NULL,
    txtvalue nvarchar(max)
)
GO
```

3. Create a Stored procedure, it will merge the same records and insert new records based on the primary key:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpsertKruserprofile]

@profile dbo.kruserprofile_type READONLY

AS

BEGIN

    MERGE dbo.kruserprofile AS target_sqldb

    USING @profile AS source_tblstg

    ON (target_sqldb.lactorid = source_tblstg.lactorid and target_sqldb.strname = source_tblstg.strname )

    WHEN MATCHED THEN

    UPDATE SET

    txtvalue = source_tblstg.txtvalue


    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

    INSERT (

        lactorid,

        strname,

        txtvalue

    )

    VALUES (

        source_tblstg.lactorid,

        source_tblstg.strname,

        source_tblstg.txtvalue
    );

END
GO
```

4. After that, we can execute the stored procedure by following code:

```sql
DECLARE @profileVar AS dbo.kruserprofile_type;
/* Add data to the table variable. */
INSERT INTO @profileVar (lactorid, strname, txtvalue) values (1, 'tom','wednesday');
exec  [dbo].[spUpsertKruserprofile] @profileVar
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks, I will upvote as your solution works. But even tho I won't use it as I do not want to use procedures if there is no real need for it.